# Form always passes validation even with empty/invalid values

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I have a simple form where I do not use an entity class.

After the post I want to validate the values using the validator, but the count of the error list is always zero even when the values are empty or invalid.

Here is (more or less) the code that I am executing:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;


    public function formAction(){
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => array(new MinLength(5)),
            'email' => array(new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address'))),
        ));

        $options = array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, $options)
                ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => '', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Your name')))
                ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => '', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'E-mail')))
                ->getForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $error   = false;
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $data      = $form->getData();
                $errorList = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($data, $collectionConstraint);

                // count($errorList) is always zero even when the values are empty or invalid…
            }
            else {
                $error = true;
            }
        }

        // ... snip ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is normal because you count the number of elements in `$errorList` inside a test that tells that the form is valid. So I would say that when the form is valid, it shows you 0, and when it's not it shows you nothing.

You don't need to run by hand the validation as it is already performed by the `$form->isValid()` statement.

if you want to count the numbers of constraint violations that have occured, just run `count($form->getErrors())` after calling `$form->isValid()`.

Finally, if it's not already done, you should definitly read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah i already got that, there are no errors.
My question is why is it not working as supposed.
It should raise errors if there is an invalid email or the fields are set to empty, when submitting the form which it is not…

I read the post you are linking to before submitting this issue at all.